# This is my dwelling Vs. this is my house?

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

The definition of a word dwelling is a house or a place of residence.

But I don't understand the difference of two.

You normally use the word house, but then when do you use dwellings?

Is the word more proper/formal?

Comment: I think *dwelling*  is a humble way to say *house.*

Comment: As a native American English speaker, I would never use dwelling conversationally. Its a semi-formal legalistic word used for regulations and insurance paperwork. I would almost always use "house" to imply the place someone lives, since I'm not drafting legal documents.

Comment: Ron Jensen is correct about "dwelling." In American English, nearly the only time "dwelling" is used in common speaking is as a verb. "I can't stop dwelling on what happened." To where "dwelling" means a kind of obsessive thinking, usually over something negative. "I can't stop thinking about what happened."

Comment: @Ron Jensen how is this word used in a sentence for insurance paperwork? I think I saw this word in a book. Is it used to tell stories or something similar?

Comment: "Dwelling" is can be used in legal matters to describe a building where people live. So a zoning law might hypothetically restrict the height of a dwelling in a neighborhood to 25 feet. Or see [this page](https://www.allstate.com/tools-and-resources/home-insurance/policies-define-dwelling.aspx) on an insurance company website that uses the word and [here's](http://www.floodsmart.com/wp-content/uploads/Dwelling-Form.pdf) another for flood insurance. The word there is being defined in a very technical legal sense to clarify exactly what is insured. You would not use it in casual conversation.

Answer (score 5):

I believe @mbakeranalecta explained Canadian English. This explanation is for American English.

**"this is my dwelling"**

You would never use "this is my dwelling" in conversation to refer to your house or home. It is very outdated. @RonJensen explains more above. You will almost never read or hear it used as a noun but only as a verb, as I explained in the other comment. Some people may use it to sound silly on purpose by using an outdated word. For example, to close friends: "Welcome guys, this is my dwelling. ;)"

**"this is my home" vs "this is my house"**

It is equally common to say "this is my home" as is "this is my house."

"This is my home" in American English is the one phrase that can be used *formally and informally* for *any type of residence*. If in doubt what to say, then say, "this is my home."

For people living in apartments they do not own, it is not common to hear, "this is my house." Instead you hear, "this is my home/apartment/place."

"This is my house" is used *formally and informally* for a standalone building, townhouse, or condo you own *or* a standalone house you rent.

"This is my place" or "this is the place" is *informal* and can be used with friends, closer contacts, or people you are already informal with.

**"place of residence"**

"Place of residence" is only used on official forms you write your street address on.

Comment: if it's outdated, does it mean that it was used long time ago?

Comment: Yes. It is good to know the phrase for older literature and articles.

Comment: I was going to add a discussion about the difference between "house" and "home" saying something about house being a less emotionally attached word. I may live in a house, but with my family I would say "home." Home may also refer to your city, especially if you are traveling.

Comment: @RonJensen True. Good points. "House" can be a less emotionally attached word than "home" and that fits my explanation, which was focused on the physical properties of a residence. It is also good to know how to speak emotionally about where one lives as you point out.

Comment: @RonJensen Perhaps it is an American difference, but the use of "house" and "home" can both be used emotionally or for status in the US. "This is _my_ house! Get out of my _house_!" "This is my home. I make the rules." "Wow! Is that your _house_?" "Your _house_ is _beautiful_!" "_Home_ is where the heart is." "This is _home_ for me." And as you say, home may also refer to your city. In the US, "hometown" is where you were born or grew up.

Answer (score 4):

"This is my house" means "I own this house."

"This is my dwelling" means "I live in this place"

A dwelling can be any place you live: house, apartment, cardboard box under a bridge.

That said, people will often use "my house" to mean the place the live, even if they don't own it.

More common still would be to say "my place".